# Generating a diff report using NDepend during build

Tags: c#, .net, build, continuous-integration, ndepend

We are using TeamCity for continuous integration, our source control is Git, and we have 1 major repository that contains multiple .sln files (around 10).

All in all, this repository has about **~ 100 - 200 C# projects**.

Upon a push to the master repository, TeamCity triggers a build that will compile **all projects in the repository**.

I'd like to be able to tell **which projects were actually affected by a particular commit**, and thus publish only those projects' outputs as artifacts of the current build.

For this, i've designed a solution to integrate NDepend into our build process, and generate a diff report between current and latest build outputs.
The outputs that were changed/added will be published as the build outputs.

I have little experience with NDepend; from what i've seen all of its true power comes from the query language that is baked into it.

I am wondering how (if possible) i can achieve the following:

1. Diff between a folder containing previous build's outputs and current folder of build outputs.
2. Have NDepend generate a report in a consumable format so i can determine the files that need to be copied.

Is this scenario possible? How easy/hard would that be?

Answer (score 5):

So the simple answer is to do the **Reporting Code Diff** way as explained in [this documentation](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Diff.aspx). The problem with this basic answer is that, it pre-suppose two NDepend projects that always refers to the two same set of assemblies.

---

Certainly, the number and names of assemblies is varying in your context so we need to build two projects (old/new) on the fly and analyze them through [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html).

Here is the NDepend.API source code for that. For a *It-Just-Works experience*, in the PowerTools source code (in `$NDependInstallDir$\NDepend.PowerTools.SourceCode\NDepend.PowerTools.sln`) just call the          `FoldersDiff.Main();` method after the `AssemblyResolve` registration call, in `Program.cs`.

```
 ...
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolverHelper.AssemblyResolveHandler;
 FoldersDiff.Main();
 ...
```

Here is the the source code that harnesses NDepend.API.

Note that so much more can be done, through the two `codeBase` objects and the `compareContext` object. Instead of just showing the 3 lists of assemblies added/removed/codeWasChanges, you could show API breakings changes, new methods and types added, modified classes and methods, code quality regression... For that, just look at [default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) concerning diff, that are based on the same [NDepend.CodeModel API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel_namespace.html).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using NDepend;
using NDepend.Analysis;
using NDepend.CodeModel;
using NDepend.Path;
using NDepend.Project;


class FoldersDiff {

   private static readonly NDependServicesProvider s_NDependServicesProvider = new NDependServicesProvider();

   internal static void Main() {
      var dirOld = @"C:\MyProduct\OldAssembliesDir".ToAbsoluteDirectoryPath();
      var dirNew = @"C:\MyProduct\NewAssembliesDir".ToAbsoluteDirectoryPath();

      Console.WriteLine("Analyzing assemblies in " + dirOld.ToString());
      var codeBaseOld = GetCodeBaseFromAsmInDir(dirOld, TemporaryProjectMode.TemporaryOlder);
      Console.WriteLine("Analyzing assemblies in " + dirNew.ToString());
      var codeBaseNew = GetCodeBaseFromAsmInDir(dirNew, TemporaryProjectMode.TemporaryNewer);

      var compareContext = codeBaseNew.CreateCompareContextWithOlder(codeBaseOld);

      // So much more can be done by exploring fine-grained diff in codeBases and compareContext
      Dump("Added assemblies", codeBaseNew.Assemblies.Where(compareContext.WasAdded));
      Dump("Removed assemblies", codeBaseOld.Assemblies.Where(compareContext.WasRemoved));
      Dump("Assemblies with modified code", codeBaseNew.Assemblies.Where(compareContext.CodeWasChanged));
      Console.Read();
   }

   internal static ICodeBase GetCodeBaseFromAsmInDir(IAbsoluteDirectoryPath dir, TemporaryProjectMode temporaryProjectMode) {
      Debug.Assert(dir.Exists);
      var dotNetManager = s_NDependServicesProvider.DotNetManager;
      var assembliesPath = dir.ChildrenFilesPath.Where(dotNetManager.IsAssembly).ToArray();
      Debug.Assert(assembliesPath.Length > 0); // Make sure we found assemblies
      var projectManager = s_NDependServicesProvider.ProjectManager;
      IProject project = projectManager.CreateTemporaryProject(assembliesPath, temporaryProjectMode);

      // In PowerTool context, better call:
      // var analysisResult = ProjectAnalysisUtils.RunAnalysisShowProgressOnConsole(project);
      var analysisResult = project.RunAnalysis();
      return analysisResult.CodeBase;
   }

   internal static void Dump(string title, IEnumerable<IAssembly> assemblies) {
      Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title));
      Debug.Assert(assemblies != null);
      Console.WriteLine(title);
      foreach (var @assembly in assemblies) {
         Console.WriteLine("   " + @assembly.Name);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome stuff there, Patrick! Looks long enough to actually work. Once i test this, i will mark as the answer.